# Auto Photo Albums in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have used Auto Photo Albums – Multi Level Image Grid for integration of my gallery in my website, it is easily integrated in core PHP but when am using codeigniter frame work for integration of this plugin am unable to get the images

The plugin consists of three files with a directory

1. reader.php
2. gallery.html

**Reader.php**

```
<?php 

  //CONFIGURATION

  $imgTypes           = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // The extensions of Images that the plugin will read
  $imagesOrder        = $_GET['imagesOrder']; //byDate, byDateReverse, byName, byNameReverse, random
  $folderCoverRandom  = $_GET['folderCoverRandom'];
  $albumsOrder        = $_GET['albumsOrder'];

  function getList ($directory, $type='none') {
    global $imgTypes;
    global $imagesOrder;
    global $albumsOrder;

    $order = $imagesOrder;

    if($type == 'albums'){
      $order = $albumsOrder;
    }

    if( !is_dir($directory)){
      return array();
    }

    $results = array();

    $handler = opendir($directory);

    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != ".DS_Store" && $file != "@eaDir") {
         $extension = preg_split('/\./',$file);
         $extension = strtolower($extension[count($extension)-1]);

         if($type == 'none'){
            //do nothing
         }else if($type == 'albums'){
            if( !is_dir($directory.'/'.$file) ){
              continue;
            }
         }else if($type == 'images'){
            if( is_dir($directory.'/'.$file) ){
              continue;
            }
         }

         if( (array_search($extension,$imgTypes) !== FALSE || is_dir($directory.'/'.$file)) && $file != "thumbnails" ){
            $ctime = filemtime($directory .'/'. $file) . ',' . $file; //BRING THE DATE OF THE IMAGE
            if($order == 'byName' || $order == 'byNameReverse'){
                $ctime = $file;
            }
            $results[$ctime] = $file;
         }   

      }
    }

    closedir($handler);
    if($order == 'byDate' || $order == 'byNameReverse'){
        krsort($results);
    }else if($order == 'byDateReverse' || $order == 'byName'){
        ksort($results);
    }else if($order == 'random'){
        shuffle($results);
    }
    return $results;

  }

  function fixArray($list, $directory){
      global $folderCoverRandom;

      $return = array();

      foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
            $val = "";

            if( is_dir($directory.'/'.$value) ){
                $val = "folder";

                $arr = getList($directory.'/'.$value); 
                $folderImg      = "";
                $folderImgCover = "";
                $thumb = 'no';

                $numImg = 0;
                $numFolders = 0;
                foreach ($arr as $key2 => $value2) {
                    if( is_dir( $directory.'/'.$value.'/'.$value2) ){//IF IT IS A FOLDER
                        $numFolders++;
                    }else{//IF IT IS AN IMAGE

                        //PICK THE FIRST IMAGES FROM THE FOLDER TO USE IT AS COVER IMAGE
                        if( $folderImg == "" ){
                            $folderImg = $value2;
                            if( file_exists( $directory.'/'.$value.'/thumbnails'.'/'.$value2 ) ){//VERIFY IF THERE IS ANY THUMBNAIL FOR THE IMAGE
                              $thumb = 'yes';
                            } 
                        }

                        //VERIFY IF THERE IS ANY "folderCover" IMAGE IN THE FOLDER SO WE CAN USE IT AS COVER IMAGE 
                        $arrName = preg_split('/\.(?=[^.]*$)/',$value2);
                        $imgName = $arrName[0];

                        if( $folderImgCover == "" && $imgName == "folderCover" ){
                            $folderImgCover = $value2;
                        }

                        if($imgName != "folderCover"){
                            $numImg++;
                        }
                    }
                }


                //PICK A RANDOM IMAGES FROM THE FOLDER TO USE IT AS RANDOM IMAGE
                if($folderCoverRandom == 'true'){
                    $rand = rand(0,$numImg-1);
                    $cont = 0;
                    foreach ($arr as $key2 => $value2) {
                        if( is_dir( $directory.'/'.$value.'/'.$value2) ){//IF IT IS A FOLDER
                            // DO NOTHING
                        }else{//IF IT IS AN IMAGE
                            if($cont == $rand){
                                $folderImg = $value2;
                                if( file_exists( $directory.'/'.$value.'/thumbnails'.'/'.$value2 ) ){//VERIFY IF THERE IS ANY THUMBNAIL FOR THE IMAGE
                                  $thumb = 'yes';
                                } 
                            }

                            $cont++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //IF THERE IS A COVER IMAGE INSIDE THE FOLDER THEN USE IT!
                if( $folderImgCover != "" ){
                    $folderImg = $folderImgCover;
                    $thumb = "no";
                }

                $val = array('numImages' => $numImg, 'numFolders' => $numFolders, 'image' => $folderImg, 'thumb' => $thumb);
            }else{
                $thumb = 'no';
                if( file_exists( $directory.'/thumbnails'.'/'.$value ) ){//VERIFY IF THERE IS ANY THUMBNAIL FOR THE IMAGE
                  $thumb = 'yes';
                } 

                $val = $thumb;
            }

            $return[$value] = $val;
      }

      return $return;
  }

  $directory = $_GET['directory'];

  //THE RESULT OF THE JSON CALL
  $output = array();

  $list = array();
  if($albumsOrder != 'none'){//Apply a different order to the folders
      $albums = getList($directory, 'albums');
      $images = getList($directory, 'images');

      $list = $albums + $images;
  }else{
      //GET LIST OF IMAGES AND FOLDERS
      $list = getList($directory);
  }


  $output = fixArray($list, $directory);

  // print_r($output);

  //echo json_encode($output, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); // if you are using PHP 5.3 plase use this line instead of the one below

  echo json_encode($output); 


?>
```

**Gallery.html**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
          <div id="grid" data-directory="Gallery"></div>
      </div>
```

All the images are loaded into the directory i,e Gallery Folder the images are retrieved into the page by using the reader file

When i have integrated the same files in codeigniter the are images are unable to load

I have created reader.php as a library and i have called it in the controller but it shows error

```
Undefined index: imagesOrder
Undefined index: folderCoverRandom
Undefined index: directory
```

Gallery Output :http://www.davidbo.dreamhosters.com/plugins/AutoAlbums/plugin/index2.html

Plugin : https://codecanyon.net/item/auto-photo-albums-multi-level-image-grid/5319229

Please help me out how can i integrate this to codeigniter

Comment: The files you've shown are just PHP I can't see how they fit in with Codeigniter?

Comment: Yes bro am also asking that how can i integrate them in codeigniter @Antony

Comment: Can you have a view on this question @Abdulla Nilam